# Confused about the ending of Fractal Prince

Tags: jean-le-flambeur, fractal-prince

It has been awhile and I'm really excited for Causal Angel in a few days. However, The [Jean le Flambeur series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fractal_Prince) is so dense with information that I've forgotten quite a bit.

I've cobbled together a lot from different wikis and sites, but one thing I'm still stuck on is:

> What happened with the All Defector at the end of the book?

Comment: You seem to be asking four different questions. Try to narrow down what you're asking (or split them into separate questions.

Comment: Much improved. I've voted to reopen

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've understood, by opening the fake Kaminari jewel Jean wiped all code within the Chen guberniya, including the copy of himself the plot of the book followed, and the copy of the All Defector he interacted with in the guberniya. But as the pellegrini-prime told Mieli immediately afterwards, the All-D was still "in many gogols across Sobornost, not as high-ranking as Matjek-Prime was, but it hasn't given up". Nothing that happened after that really dealt with the All-D, so I would assume it was left infecting the Sobornost.